# To extract only specific characters using Regex in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to extract specific characters like brackets (not the elements within it), *, # etc and replace it with ' '. So I compiled my pattern like below

```
p = re.compile(r'\s([\[]).*|\s([\(]).*|\s([#]).*|\s([\{]).*|\s([\*]).*|\s([\<]).*|\s.*(\>)\s|\s.* 
      (\])\s|\s.*(\))\s|\s.*(#)\s|\s.*(\*)\s|\s.*(\})\s')
string = "hello (you) "
for match in re.finditer(p, string):
  print(match.group())
```

This gives the output:

```
(you)
```

But what I am expecting is match to give the output list with the captured group like below

```
["(",")"]
```

so that I can replace it with '  ' and have the desired output as

```
hello you

Input: Abnormal heart rate (with fever) should be monitored. Insert your <Name> here.
Output:Abnormal heart rate with fever should be monitored. Insert your Name here.
```

Comment: If you just want to remove certain characters, you don't need a regex.

Comment: Can you add more sample data which shows what you are trying to capture (other than `(you)`) ?

Comment: Why do you expect it to return `(,)` when there is no comma in the input string?

Comment: Why are you using alternatives instead of `[[(#{*<>...]`?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to escape most special characters inside `[]`.

Comment: You can't have a newline in a string literal unless you use triple-quotes around it.

Comment: And if you put a newline in a regexp, it will be matched literally.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I have edited it with some more input. Please find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to replace terms in parentheses or angle brackets with only the content inside them.  That is:

```
(with fever) -> with fever
<Name> -> Name
```

We can try using `re.sub` here with a callback function:

```
inp = "Abnormal heart rate (with fever) should be monitored. Insert your <Name> here."
print(re.sub(r'\(.*?\)|<.*?>', lambda x: re.sub(r'[()<>]', '', x.group(0)), inp))
```

This prints:

```
Abnormal heart rate with fever should be monitored. Insert your Name here.
```

The logic here is that we selectively target the `(...)` and `<...>` terms using an alternation.  Then, we pass the entire match to a lambda callback which then replaces the surrounding symbols with just the content.

Answer (score 0):

Just list all the characters you want to remove in a single character set, and use `re.sub()` to remove them.

```
print(re.sub(r'[[\](){}<>#*]', '', string))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can proceed with replace all with space expect A-Z a-z if you also want digits 0-9 you can specify.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String string = "hello (you) hai";
              String result =string.replaceAll("[^A-Z a-z]","");
      System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

This will work but here we are using replaceAll();

Comment: OP asked a Python solution.